# Do I need to install Android Studio if I already have Intellij IDEA Ultimate?

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea

Currently, I have IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate installed. I want to develop an Android app. Do I need to install Android Studio?

Comment: All features from Android Studio are available in IDEA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> No. Android Studio is focused specifically on Android development and
> provides streamlined environment and project setup, but otherwise all
> of its features are available in IntelliJ IDEA.

-- [JetBrains](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/207675385-Should-current-IntelliJ-IDEA-user-use-Android-Studio-for-Android-development-)

Android Studio and IntelliJ changes for Android related functionality are kept in sync (both ways). Android Studio is free but has only a subset of functionality of IntelliJ.